# GLES 2.0+ Alpha not showing

Tags: android, opengl-es

So I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0, I'm rendering transparent objects one on top of another, everything appears to be working however if I go below 0.05 in my fragment shader, nothing renders. My render config is set to:

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glDisable(GL_DITHER);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(false);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

I've tried both GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE and GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 as render target texture types with no luck.

Is there anything else I can do to improve the precision of the alpha value, and  blending? With 0.05 as the minimum alpha value, it gives me only 20(1.0/0.05=20) values to work with. Basically I'm treating the render texture as an array of data and using a vertex shader to add values to different pixels.

EDIT: I'm using float highp, doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what precision you use in the shader - perhaps you should set it to highdp (in fragment shader), see if this helps:

```
precision highp float;
```

(If you need to know exatly what precision you need, you can use glGetShaderPrecisionFormat)

Comment: You shouldn't need highp; mediump (fp16) is more than precise enough to handle many more decimal places of precision than 2dp.

Comment: Well for what ever reason it just doesn't work at anything below 0.05 seems like it's a hard cutoff point as 0.049 also doesn't work. For what I'm doing the lower the value I can get to work the better.